# Bluetooth architecture on Webos

Tags: bluetooth, webos, bluez

What are the IPC mechanisms used in webos for bluez connection, also to develop any bluetooth profile in webos, are the proper methods exposed or bluetooth , can someone explain me on the luna bus interaction with bluez ?

Answer (score 0):

Luna-bus system is used in webos for bluez connection.

"com.palm.bt" is a Luna service name for webos bluetooth. Methods such as connect, write, read and close should be defined in bluetooth adapter and you can use this method using luna-send command. You can find the luna-send command example here: http://www.openwebosproject.org/docs/developer_guide/tools/luna_send/#.Uliv2mQqd1M

Comment: thanks for your comments, after bit research in net, found that webOS does not support bluez, my understanding it uses some custom BT stack, com.palm.bt Luna service should be for that particular bt stack